# Add second application class to android project

Tags: android

I'm following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)  to add a application class to initialize my application, i did as follow:
**Initialisation.java**

```
package com.thinline.dm21.init;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

public class Initialisation extends Application{

  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i("Test","Executed");
  }     
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.thinline.dm21"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.thinline.dm21.calendrier.Calendrier"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"        
        android:name="com.thinline.dm21.init.Initialisation">       
</application>

</manifest>
```

but i dont see my message in the logcat. What am i missing ?

Comment: Is there a question you are asking here?

EDIT:Much Better, Thanks :)

Comment: Why would you need a second Application? You could just set the android:name attribute in the first one.

Comment: yes it is in the bottom of the message "but i dont see my message in the logcat. What am i missing ?", normally i should be able te see the Log.i() who's in the onCreate method of Initialisation, but nothing shows

Comment: @BerndS, i need it to execute some initialisation code, i could have done it in my activity'onCreate method, but when i rotate my tablet, the onCreate is called a second time

Comment: @Blacksword888: My point was that you have already an application specified. You can do it there. See mah's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining the <application> in your manifest twice. Merge it into a single entry. (That is, move the `android:name` out of the second entry into the first, then delete the second.)

Comment: thank you, it worked.
now, i just want to understand how to add one or multiple Application class (Maybe one for handling Global variables)

Comment: Your manifest can describe only a single application (and your APK can contain only a single application); this is by design. An "application" is really just a container hold one 0 or more activities, broadcast receivers, etc.